# Jest unit test of private variable in Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

In my angular service I am using a private variable and writing unit test using Jest.
My service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
  private value = '';

  removeValue(): void {
    this.value='';
  }

  setNewValue(value : string): void {
    this.value = value;
  }

  simpleEmptyMethod() {
  }
}
```

Unit Test file sample.service.spec.ts:

```
describe('sampleservice', () => {
   let sampleService : SampleService;
   beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers : [SampleService]
      });
      sampleService=TestBed.get(SampleService);
   });

   it('should be created', () => {
     expect(sampleService).toBeTruthy();
   })

   it('should remove Value', () => {
     sampleService.removeValue();
     expect(sampleService.value).toBe('');
   })

   it('should set new value', () => {
       sampleService.setNewValue('abc');
       expect(sampleService.value).expect('abc');
   })

})
```

I a, getting an error like 'value is undefined'. This might be because the value is private within the service class & what will be the approach to cover empty method  as the body of the method will be defined in future.
How to handle this scenario?

Comment: It's private, you can't access it. Make it public, or mock the value in your test class, or write a method getValue() to get the value and call that method.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error. Even though the variable is private and you *shouldn't* be accessing it, it's still possible. [Here's a stackblitz demonstrating the tests passing.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-b51j1v?file=app%2Fsample.service.spec.ts) You'll note that the tests still run and pass, but the IDE is telling me:

> "Property 'value' is private and only accessible within class
>   'SampleService'"

I'd recommend:

1. Make sure you're testing against the interface and not the implementation.
2. If you need to inspect the state of this service, either make the `value` property public, or add a public `getValue()` function.